# Do I need to install old patches after installing Magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, patch

I just download and installed Magento community edition version 1.9.2.4. Do I need to install old patches, including 7405? And have any patches for Magento community edition 1.9.2.4 been released yet? I see a notification that shows "You have 13 critical updates". What should I do now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

you can scan your site [here](http://magereport.com/) & it will give what and all security measures you need to take....

Answer (score 0):

Ignore notifications related to patch, this version already have all patches inside. You just have to scan on magereport.com when your shop url is available online.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.9.2.4 included all security patches you do not need to install any patch, just ignore notification and check your online store url from [here](https://www.magereport.com/)